# stripe.setupIntents.create({}, {}) fails

Tags: stripe-payments

I've tried `stripe.setupIntents.create({}, {})` but it fails with `Stripe: Unknown arguments ([object Object])`.
Is it normal ?

`stripe.setupIntents.create()` works

**Complete example:**

```
stripeSetupIntent: async function() {

  const stripe = require("stripe")(Meteor.settings.stripe.private_key);

  try {
    const intent = await stripe.setupIntents.create({}, {});
    // [...]
    return intent.client_secret;
  }
  catch(e) {
    orbiter.core.error('stripeSetupIntent: ' + e.message, ['stripe']);
    throw e;
  }
},
```

Comment: Can you share a complete working example of this that could be used to reproduce the error?  Also the whole stack would be useful, as would the version of `stripe-node` you're using.

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. Stripe node npm version is 8.25.0. The web framework is Meteor.

Comment: The call will work as just `stripe.setupIntents.create({})` at least. I think the issue is the library doesn't expect you to pass an empty object for the second param. That param is used for passing things like idempotency keys or the stripeAccount option, there's no reason for it be passed as an empty object versus just omitting it so the library probably doesn't expect you to do it.